# Can I ignore Example data to not to include in cucumber HTML report

Tags: cucumber, cucumberjs, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I am using cucumber with java and maven.

I am using cucumber example data in feature file.

But requirement is we do not want to include example data in report in gherkin statements.

Example:

```
 Scenario Outline: Looking up the definition of fruits
    Given the user is on the Wikionary home page
    When the user looks up the definition of the word <name>
    Then they should see the definition 'An edible fruit produced by the pear tree, similar to an apple but elongated towards the stem.'
    Examples:
    | name |
    | pear |
```

Now the report will have the statement as below:

```
When the user looks up the definition of the word **pear**
```

I do not want to include pear as an word in report

Any way around will be helpful !!

Comment: Which report are u using?

Comment: Default one ... I m not using advance report .. report build by cucumber from pretty report using json

Comment: @Grasshopper - is it any way available in advance report ? ... Please let me know so I can see the alternatives in case this facility is not available in default reports

Comment: Not sure if there is a report for ur needs. Though u can extend the pretty report and include as a custom plugin in cucumberoptions.

Comment: Hey @Grasshopper .. I am using now cucumber extendable reports .. details: https://github.com/damianszczepanik/maven-cucumber-reporting

Comment: Can we hide data partially in this report? .. or do you know any report which has ability to hide example test data